# Calculate $\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{\sqrt[x]{1} + \sqrt[x]{2}}{2}\bigg)^x$

Tags: limits

I am just tryin to solve the limit:

$$\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{\sqrt[x]{1} + \sqrt[x]{2}}{2}\bigg)^x$$

(hope this isn't a duplicate, it is quite complicated to find special eq's via the search engine here)
Wolfram-alpha told me it is $\sqrt{2}$. I have thought about using L'Hospital but the denominators derivatives to $f^{(n)} = (\ln2)^n \cdot 2^x \to \infty \; \forall n$.

So I don't see the use of it.

Hints are very welcome. (I already seen that $\sqrt[x]{1} = 1$ and tried the $e^{\ln f(x)}$ but without success)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x= e^{\log x} $ and write $\frac{1}{x}=h$, so you have $\frac{\log (1+2^h)-\log 2 }{h}$, then use L'Hospital

Comment: Somewhat pedantic point: as is often the case, you've rewritten this as the definition of the derivative of $\ln \left ( 1 + 2^x \right )$ at $x=0$. So L'Hospital's rule is not necessary. Still nice, +1.

Comment: @Ian: This is exactly what I was trying to do (my favorite approach if you look at my similar answers), but for sm reasong couldn't get my head around making it precise, so jumped to L'H

Comment: Yup, works quite good; thank you. I haven't used L'Hospital here, chain rule is known :)

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
y = \lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{\sqrt[x]{1} + \sqrt[x]{2}}{2}\bigg)^x =
\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{1 + 2^{1/x}}{2}\bigg)^x
$$
So, 
$$
\ln y =
\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} x\ln\bigg(\frac{1 + 2^{1/x}}{2}\bigg) = 
\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \ln\bigg(\frac{1 + 2^{1/x}}{2}\bigg)/(1/x)
$$
L'Hopital gives you
$$
\ln y = \lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{2}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\bigg) \cdot (-1/x^2)[\ln(2)/2]2^{1/x}/(-1/x^2) = \\
\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{2[\ln(2)/2]2^{1/x}}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\bigg) = \\
2[\ln(2)/2]
\lim_{x\, \to \,\infty} \bigg(\frac{2^{1/x}}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\bigg) =\\
2[\ln(2)/2] \frac 12 = \ln(2)/2
$$
So, we have $y = e^{\ln(2)/2} = \sqrt 2$.  So the limit is $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the natural log of the argument of the limit:

$$
\ln\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt[x]{2}}{2}\Bigr)^x = x[\ln(1+\sqrt[x]{2})-\ln 2]
$$

Now, in the limit, $[1+(\ln 2)/x]^x$ goes as $e^{\ln 2} = 2$, so $\sqrt[x]{2}$ goes as $1+(\ln 2)/x$.  So the log of our argument now goes as $x[\ln(2+(\ln 2)/x)-\ln 2]$.

Observe that $d/du (\ln u) = 1/u = 1/2$ at $u = 2$, so the above expression goes as $x[\ln 2+(\ln 2)/(2x)-\ln 2] = (\ln 2)/2$.  Since that is the log of our expression, the desired limit is $e$ raised to that power, or $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this. Let $T(x)=a^x$. Then $T'(x)=a^x \ln(a)$ and so $T(0)=1$ and $T'(0)=\ln(a)$. $T'(0)=\ln(a)=\lim_{ u \rightarrow 0 } \frac{T(u)-T(0)}{u-0}=\lim_{ u \rightarrow 0 } \frac{a^u-1}{u} $ Let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ . This means we have: $\ln(a)=\lim_{ u \rightarrow \infty } (a^\frac{1}{x}-1)x$ So let's go back and play around with our problem: $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{\sqrt[x]{1} + \sqrt[x]{2}}{2})^x=\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{(2^\frac{1}{x}-1)x}{2x}+1)^{2x \cdot \frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} ((\frac{\ln(2)}{2x}+1)^{2x})^\frac{1}{2}=(e^{\ln(2)})^\frac{1}{2}$ Now if we can do this you might have to beef up some of what I have said. I will add for some small $\epsilon>0$ and large $x$ we have $\ln(a)=(a^\frac{1}{x}-1)x+\epsilon$ And so $\ln(a) \approx (a^\frac{1}{x}-1)x$