# Calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}})^x$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}})^x$.

First off, it's easy to see that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}}$ = 1. Therefore, I tried the following:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}})^x=
\lim_{x\to \infty}(1 +(\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}} -1))^x = e^{\lim_{x\to \infty}x(\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}} -1)}.$$

Now I find myself stuck at finding $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(\frac{\sqrt[x]{2} + \sqrt[x]{3}} {\sqrt[x]{4} + \sqrt[x]{5}} -1)$. Keep in mind that I am not allowed to use l'Hopital. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247239/42969 for a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Let the limit exist and equal $L$. Then $\ln L$ equals:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\left(\ln\left(2^{1/x}+3^{1/x}\right)-\ln\left(4^{1/x}+5^{1/x}\right)\right)$$

and making the substitution $u \mapsto 1/x$ gives:

$$\lim_{u \to 0^+} \frac{1}{u} \left(\ln\left(2^u+3^u\right)-\ln\left(4^u+5^u\right)\right)$$

Considering the first-order approximation of $f(u) = \ln\left(2^u+3^u\right)$ using Taylor series, $f(0) = \ln 2$. $f'(u) = \frac{1}{2^u + 3^u} \cdot (2^u \ln 2 + 2^u \ln 3)$, hence $f'(0) = \frac{\ln 6}{2}$. Doing this for the other composite function gives:

$$\ln L = \lim_{u \to 0^+} \frac{1}{u} \left(\ln 2 + \frac{\ln 6}{2}u - \ln 2 - \frac{\ln 20}{2} u \right) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{3}{10}$$

hence $L = e^{\ln(3/10) \cdot 1/2} = \sqrt{3/10} \approx 0.548$.

Comment: A sanity check is useful at the end of this to verify that $\frac{2}{4} ≤ L ≤ \frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: Using the first-order approximation is implicitly invoking L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Yes, it invokes the spirit of L'Hopital's rule without all the nasty computations. I would be interested if someone else had another way.

Comment: But we can avoid relying on the fact that the function is analytic and all that by just noting that $\lim_{u \to 0+} f(u)/u$ is a derivative $f'(0)$ by definition.

Comment: I see your point: how about you write another answer based on my one?

Comment: Feel free to edit your own answer with that simplification.

Answer (score 2):

In fact $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{a}+\sqrt[x]{b}}{2}\right)^x=\sqrt{ab}$ for $a,\,b>0$. This is [a comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Geometric_mean) (in the $2$-variable unweighted case) of power means to the geometric mean. Now just take the ratio of two cases.